# Store pandastable dataframe into variable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I currently have the below script that reads an imported csv file and displays as `pandastable` in the `tkinter` GUI.

As the file is imported its adds x2 additional columns `self.table.addColumn("Current Status")` and `self.table.addColumn("Assign Technician")`.

How can I store the updated `pandastable dataframe` into a variable outside of `class TestApp(tk.Frame):` so that I can call other functions on the `dataframe` later in my code?

I have used the `global` variable before so that I can call a `variable` created from within a function outside of it later but not sure if thats what I need for this purpose.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.title('Workshop Manager')


def select_input_file():
    global input_file_path
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode = INSIDE,height = 500, width = 2000, x =0, y=50)
    

class TestApp(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, input_file_path, editable = True, enable_menus = True):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.table = Table(self, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
        self.table.importCSV(input_file_path)
        self.table.show(input_file_path)
        self.table.addColumn('Current Status')
        self.table.addColumn('Assign Technician')
        self.table.autoResizeColumns()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a `global` variable here. You can directly access the member attributes of a class by using the object itself. So in this case, you can access the `table` attr of the class `TestApp` using `app.table`, which would look something like this,

```
def select_input_file():
    #...
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode = INSIDE,height = 500, width = 2000, x =0, y=50)

    df = app.table     # contains the updated table which can be passed to other functions
    newFunc( df )      # sample call
```

Comment: if I use `df = app.table` then `print(df)` i get output `.!testapp.!table` which is the object name?

Comment: Yes that is the table object, if you want to print the dataframe inside it, you can get it from `df = app.table.model.df` then do `print(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `global` to achieve this.

Currently, all your stateful variables exist in the module (file).  You can do the same for your table, outside of `TestApp`, and then pass it though `__init__`:

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel


table = Table(showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.title('Workshop Manager')


def select_input_file():
    global input_file_path
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode = INSIDE,height = 500, width = 2000, x =0, y=50)
    

class TestApp(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, input_file_path, editable = True, enable_menus = True, table=table):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.table = table
        self.table.importCSV(input_file_path)
        self.table.show(input_file_path)
        self.table.addColumn('Current Status')
        self.table.addColumn('Assign Technician')
        self.table.autoResizeColumns()

root.mainloop()
```

Your table object is now accessible to anything that can see the module namespace.  Here `table` is a mutable object, and all changes will be reflected to any function that accesses that object.

One suggestion: it is preferable to separate out your definitions (classes, functions) from your stateful bits that are created at run time.  This will greatly help clarify dependencies.  It is typical to use the line `if __name__ == "__main__":` at the bottom of the file to start the "script" part of your app, keeping all definitions above.  I've seen some packages (looking at you, Flask!) break this convention a bit, and it can cause headaches.

On that note, your `select_input_file` function has a few issues.  There's no good reason to create an app instance there.  A better option would be to make this a method in the `App` class for example.